# How to check the intermediate value in the dll function made by c++ in VBA

Tags: c++, vba, dll

Thank you for your help.
Now I'm making a dll file including some functions by c++.
I want to check the intermediate value in the dll function from VBA.
The below codes are the examples of the C++ and VBA codes.

cpp code

```
double __stdcall Inp(double* x, double* y)
{
double *a;
double b;
a[0]=x[0]*y[0];
a[1]=x[1]*y[1];

b=a[0]*a[1];
return b;
}
```

VBA code

```
 x(0) = 3
 x(1) = 5
 y(0) = 4
 y(1) = 5

 Debug.Print (Inp(x(0), y(0)))
```

The array values of x(0) to y(1) are sent to dll and calculate something.
At the above code, I can see the calculation result of "b" by Debug function.
This is OK but I also want to check a[0] and a[1] value in the VBE.
Is there any way to check it in VBE?
I've tried to check it by OutputDebugString() function but there're no variables appeared in the local, immediate window.
Of course I can check the each intermediate value by splitting the functions but it's not effective.
If there're some way to check the intermediate value with one function, it's very appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question. It sounds like `Debug.Print (Inp(x(0), y(0)))` gives you the results of `Inp` when the macro is run. Do you want to see the value of `Inp(x(0), y(0))` while you are coding in the VBE instead? That expression is only evaluated while the code is running, so that would not be possible.